# Recharts BarChartStackedBySign - Is it possible to show same entity on both side of Y axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

In BarChartStackedBySign of Recharts, i want to compare the given entities for current and previous year representing that on bar graph.

The issue is re-charts treats them as different entity if provided via two different objects.

In the fiddle shared we can see each fruit is represented two times on x-axis, i want each fruit comes only one time on x-axis and data for current year gets represented on +y axis and previous year data on -y axis.

Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/59ugdj1t/

```
const {BarChart, Bar, ReferenceLine, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;

// Data for current year
const data1 = [
      {name: 'Apple', men: 4000, women: 2400},
      {name: 'Orange', men: 2000, women: 2000},
      {name: 'Kiwi', men: 1000, women: 1400},
];

// Data for previous year
const data2 = [
      {name: 'Apple', men: -3000, women: -2000},
      {name: 'Orange', men: -1000, women: -1000},
      {name: 'Kiwi', men: -2000, women: -400},
];

const data = data1.concat(data2);

const SimpleBarChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data} stackOffset="sign"
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <ReferenceLine y={0} stroke='#000'/>
       <Bar dataKey="men" fill="#8884d8" stackId="stack" />
       <Bar dataKey="women" fill="#82ca9d" stackId="stack" />
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleBarChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: jest have one array and several bars. check this: https://jsfiddle.net/59ugdj1t/7/

Comment: @igorves, using this strategy we have changed men -> menPr for previous data(i.e. created different keys for different data), which actually i don't want.

Comment: oh, got it, okay